# How to change text column to values using panda

Tags: python, pandas

With Panda dataframes, how can I change a generic text column ['A'] into an integer value column ['A'], so that some word becomes some value. I'm not asking to calculate a value, I'm asking to replace some text by some number.

```
table before        table after
     A                  A
 0   w               0  2
 1   q               1  11
 2   st              2  1
 3   R               3  7
 4   Prt             4  6
```

Replace it so `R` becomes `7`, `st` becomes `1`

Pseudo code:

```
df['A'] = df.convert('w'=2, 'q'=11, 'st'=1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a dictionary indicating how the replace should be done.

```
import pandas as pd

df_before = pd.DataFrame({'A':['w','q','st','R','Prt']})

d = {'w':2, 'q':11, 'st':1, 'R': 7, 'Prt':6}

df_after = df_before.replace(d)

print(df_after)
```

Output:

```
    A
0   2
1  11
2   1
3   7
4   6
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm not so sure why such a question gets so downvoted here, people never asume that others might try to learn a new language and are new to commands and syntaxes

Comment: Hi @user613326  , try to make questions generic, simple, neat and useful for others. After all, it all about what you could lean. Not how much reputation you could earn  (I haven't down voted).

Comment: i tried to keep it simple , i think people where to much thinking in algorithms and not seeing the plain logic in front of them. Reminds me of some IQ tests